# Easy way to handle external data from uri in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-contentprovider

Is there easy way to handle as much as can content providers in android. My application must handle text, images and documents but after adding support for Google Drive content provider, for Google Photos, for media and so on and so on...
Now when sharing to my application Google Keep note with image and text, my application crash.

This is snippet of how I use it now:

```
public class IntentUtils {
public static String handlePDFIntent(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (uri != null) {
        return getPath(context, uri);
    }
    return "";
}

public static String handleTextIntent(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null) {
        return sharedText;
    }
    return "";
}

public static String handleImageIntent(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Uri imageUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    if (imageUri != null) {
        return getPath(context, imageUri);
    }

    return "";
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageRemovable() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD || Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable();
}

public static File getExternalCacheDir(Context context) {
    if (hasExternalCacheDir()) {
        return context.getExternalCacheDir();
    }

    // Before Froyo we need to construct the external cache dir ourselves
    final String cacheDir = "/Android/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/cache/";
    return new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + cacheDir);
}

public static boolean hasExternalCacheDir() {
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String format = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(format)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String format = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            switch (format) {
                case "image":
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    break;
                case "video":
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    break;
                case "audio":
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                    break;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        if (isDriveStorageDocument(uri) || isPlusPhotosDocument(uri) || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            try {
                ParcelFileDescriptor parcel = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                final InputStream is = new FileInputStream(parcel.getFileDescriptor());
                final File cacheDir;

                if (externalMemoryAvailable()) {
                    cacheDir = context.getExternalCacheDir();
                } else {
                    cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
                }

                final String type = context.getContentResolver().getType(uri);
                String ext = "pdf";

                if (type.startsWith("image")) {
                    if (type.toLowerCase().contains("jpg") || type.toLowerCase().contains("jpeg")) {
                        ext = "jpg";
                    } else if (type.toLowerCase().contains("png")) {
                        ext = "png";
                    }
                }

                cacheDir.mkdirs();
                File out = new File(cacheDir, "tmp_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + ext);

                FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(is, out);
                is.close();
                parcel.close();

                System.out.println(Uri.fromFile(out).getPath());

                return Uri.fromFile(out).getPath();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    } else {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context       The context.
 * @param uri           The Uri to query.
 * @param selection     (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isDriveStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return uri.getAuthority().startsWith("com.google.android.apps.docs.storage");
}

public static boolean isKeepNote(Uri uri) {
    return uri.getAuthority().startsWith("com.google.android.keep");
}

public static boolean isPlusPhotosDocument(Uri uri) {
    return uri.getAuthority().startsWith("content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content");
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public static boolean isDebuggable(Context ctx) {
    boolean debuggable = false;

    PackageManager pm = ctx.getPackageManager();
    try {
        final ApplicationInfo appinfo = pm.getApplicationInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), 0);
        debuggable = (0 != (appinfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {/*debuggable variable will remain false*/}

    return debuggable;
}

public static boolean externalMemoryAvailable() {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
}
```

}

Update 1:
It seems Google keep use clipboard data and some blobs, but I'm looking for more general method to handle external content providers. Any help?